# Unlearning Neural Network? Prevent learning from a specific feature

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data, conv-neural-network, convolution

Is it possible to train a NN to avoid the features that a different neural network finds? For example, let's train a simple 1 layer CNN with 1x1 kernels on a supervised binary classification problem. Then train a CNN with 2x2 kernel so that it doesn't learn any of the features from the 1x1 network?

Phrased another way, whatever the dominant feature of the 1x1 network is, I want my 2x2 network to avoid.

For example, say we were learning MNIST with just 0, 1 digits. However, all the zeros are in black, and the ones in white. So the 1x1 CNN just learns the color "if the picture is mostly black -> 1, else 0". It doesn't actually learn the shapes, just the average color. Now if I train a 2x2 CNN, it might learn both the color and something about the shape. Can I set this color dependance to zero? 'Unlearn' this feature?

Comment: You may want to look into generative adversarial networks where the descriminator network must learn new features which the generative network has not learned

Comment: What you are looking for might be the machine unlearning problem as described in this paper: [Machine Unlearning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.03817.pdf). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can always introduce adversarial network or just forge examples with high weight that will force NN to make mistake, raise **loss** and then it will have to learn other features, still adversarial network is best because it could do it automatically!